# How to plot and change the order of integration of the following double integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to plot and change the order of the following double integral $\int_0^{{\pi}/2} \int_1^2 f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$

I got something like this when I plotted it.

[Image is HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQQNQ.png)

My guess is that the boundaries for both $x$ and $y$ are constant values, so if I change the order of integration, I get this $\int_1^2 \int_0^{{\pi}/2} f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$

I might be completely wrong, please help me out.

Comment: Yes this is likely correct for your problem. For the exact conditions in which this is possible see [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).

Comment: What's $f(x,y)$?

Comment: @allawonder just any function with two variables x and y

Comment: @Eric Then that's trivially false if we take a nonintegrable  function for $f(x,y).$